# A Decomposition for Iitaka fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, fibration, minimal-model-program

> Let $\pi:  X\to Y$ be an Iitaka fibration of projective varieties
>   $X,Y$, then is there always the following decomposition
>
> $$K_Y+\frac{1}{m!}\pi_*\mathcal O_X(m!K_{X/Y})=P+N$$
>
> where $P$ is semiample and $N$ is effective and
>
> $$H^0(Y,\mathcal O_X(maP))\cong H^0(X,\mathcal O(ma(K_X+\frac{1}{m!}\pi_*\mathcal O_X(m!K_{X/Y}))))$$
>
> holds for every $m\geq 0$ and some positive integer $a$ and $P,N\in
>  Div(X)$?
>
> I think, such decomposition is correct due to Higher canonical bundle
>   formula of Fujino-Mori, but I am not sure.

Comment: I added a reference from E. Viehweg which say that such decomposition is in the nature of Fujino-Mori's canonical bundle formula arxiv.org/pdf/0707.4287.pdf as I mentioned in my question also. By this question I wanted to be ensure that the main such decomposition is due to  Higher canonical bundle formula of Fujino-Mori, Also Kawamata gave such decomposition before of Fujino-Mori,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is smooth (projective over the complex numbers), then $R(K_X)$ is finitely generated by BCHM. We may thus assume that $R(kK_X)$ is generated in degree 1 for some $k>0$. Passing to a log resolution of $|kK_X|$ we may assume that $|kK_X|=M+F$ where $F$ is the fixed divisor and $M$ is base point free and so $M$ defines a morphism $f:X\to Y$ which is the Iitaka fibration. Thus $M=f^*O_Y(1)$ is semiample and $F$ is effective, and $H^0(O_Y(m))=H^0(O_X(mM))=H^0(O_X(mkK_X))$.
Fujino-Mori's canonical bundle formula (their theorem 5.2) is in fact used in the proof of the finite generation of $R(K_X)$ by relating $R(K_X)$ to $R(K_Y+B_Y)$ where $(Y,B_Y)$ is klt, $K_Y+B_Y$ is big and $X\to Y$ is (a birational model of) the Iitaka fibration.

Comment: What about when $X$ has mild singularities? then $R(K_X)$ is f.g. Moreover, your answer give such decomposition $K_Y+\frac{1}{m!}\pi_*\mathcal O_X(m!K_{X/Y})=P+N$ ?

Comment: It works if $X$ is log terminal. Using Fujino-Mori 5.2, after resolving $X'$, we get a morphism $X'\to Y'$ and a klt pair $K_{Y'}+B_{Y'}$. The $Y$ described above is the log canonical model of $K_{Y'}+B_{Y'}$ and so in fact (assuming as above that $Y'\to Y$ is a morphism), then $K_{Y'}+B_{Y'}\sim _Q P+N$ where $P$ is the pull-back of a rational multiple of $O_Y(1)$ and $N$  is effective (the stable fixed divisor). If $Y'--->Y$ is not a morphism, then $P$ will have a base locus corresponding to the indeterminacy locus of this map.

Comment: I added a reference from E. Viehweg which say that such decomposition is in the nature of Fujino-Mori's canonical bundle formula https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.4287.pdf as I mentioned in my question also. This thesis also is a good reference to answer of Hacon https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01124199v2/document